# KeyError: 'type' Clarifai

Tags: python, clarifai

I'm starting on a project using Clarifai. However, when I define the app, I'm getting a key error:

```
from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp
from clarifai.rest import Image as ClImage
import os
from glob import glob

api_key = 'my api key'
app = ClarifaiApp(api_key=api_key) # Error occurs here
model_id = 'model id'
concepts = ['concept1', 'concept2', 'concept3']
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crayo\uShoe\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = ClarifaiApp(api_key=api_key)
  File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\clarifai\rest\client.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.models = Models(self.api, self.solutions)  # type: Models
  File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\clarifai\rest\client.py", line 1068, in __init__
    self.model_id_cache = self.init_model_cache()
  File "C:\Users\user\project\venv\lib\site-packages\clarifai\rest\client.py", line 1088, in init_model_cache
    model_type = m.output_info['type']
KeyError: 'type'
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, so if someone could provide input I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 2):

- You are using the deprecated Python REST package: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-python. Please replace your code with the new & updated Python gRPC client: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-python-grpc
- Make sure to uninstall the REST package to avoid conflicts.
- You can find our API docs & code snippets here: https://docs.clarifai.com